# How to shoot backwards in Cocoa2d Game

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am having a brain freeze at the moment.

I have a tank on the bottom of the screen. The code below shoots a missile at the spaceship, if the spaceship is on the right of the tank.

How do I get it to shoot a missile if the tank is on the left side of the tank at the bottom of the screen?

The RealDest only seems to work when the target is on the right of the missile start point.

Thank you for your help.

Cheers

Shane

```
int offX = Spaceship.position.x - missile.position.x;  
int offY = Spaceship.position.y - missile.position.y;  

// Determine where we wish to shoot the projectile to   
int realX = winSize.width + (missile.contentSize.width/2);  
float ratio = (float) offY / (float) offX;  
int realY = (realX * ratio) + missile.position.y;  
CGPoint realDest = ccp(realX, realY);  

// Determine the length of how far we're shooting  
int offRealX = realX - missile.position.x;  
int offRealY = realY - missile.position.y;  
float length = sqrtf((offRealX*offRealX)+(offRealY*offRealY));  
float velocity = 480/1; // 480pixels/1sec  
float realMoveDuration = length/velocity;  


[missile runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:realMoveDuration position:realDest]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to shoot at the spaceship, shouldn't you have

```
realDest = ccp(Spaceship.position.x, Spaceship.position.y);
```

Comment: The realDest gives the correct position of the Spaceship when the tank at the ottom of the screen is on the left side of the Spachip. If on the right of the Spaceship then there is no missile fired.